# Prove that $f_n \to f$ in the metric of $C(R)$, iff $f_n \to f$ uniformly on every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $f_n$ be a sequence in $C(R)$. Then $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the metric of $C(R)$, iff $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Here, the metric on $C(R)$ is $$d(f,g):=\sum_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{d_n(f,g)}{1+d_n(f,g)}, \text{where } d_n(f,g)=\max_{|t|\le n}|f(t)-g(t)|$$

While the left $\to$ right implication is trivial, I was not able to prove the other direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the other direction, assume that $f_k$ converges uniformly to $g$ on every compact subset of $\Bbb R$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$ we have to show that $d(f_k, g) < \epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $k$. The idea is to split the sum into a finite part and a remainder. The first part becomes small because $d_n(f_k, g) \to 0$ for every $n$, and the second part becomes small because each term is less than $1/2^n$. Concretely:
$$
 d(f_k, g) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{d_n(f_k,g)}{1+d_n(f_k,g)} + \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{d_n(f_k,g)}{1+d_n(f_k,g)} \\
\le \sum_{n=1}^{N} d_n(f_k,g) + \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}
\le N d_N(f_k, g) + \frac{1}{2^N} \, .
$$
Now choose $N$ such that  $\frac{1}{2^N} < \frac 12 \epsilon$, and then $K$ sufficiently large that $ N d_N(f_k, g) < \frac 12 \epsilon$ for $k \ge K$.

Comment: Could you explain the other part, please? I was able to do the left-right part exactly like your proof, but the right-left part was not clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: @TheMathematician: For each $n$ is $d(f,g) \ge \frac{1}{2^n}\frac{d_n(f,g)}{1+d_n(f,g)}$, so that $d(f_k, f) \to 0$ implies that $d_n(f_k, f) \to 0$ for all $n$, that is $f_k \to f$ uniformly on all circles $|z| \le n$.

Comment: Oh that's so clear, thank you very much. What confuses me is the $n$, I imagined it moving. Thank you very much.